# Javascript getting object properties

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create a `google.Visualization.DataTable`in the end, to show a graph. By now, I have a Problem with the following:

This is my code for getting `Object` from `JSON-string` and listing Properties:

```
var jsonData = <?php echo "'". $jsonTable. "'"; ?>;
var parsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);

var sensors = [];

for (var x in parsed){
    sensors.push(parsed[x]);
}
var text ="";
for (var sensor in sensors){
    if (sensors.hasOwnProperty(sensor)){
        var measures = sensors[sensor];
        text += ('\r\n' + sensor);
        for (var time in measures){
            if(measures.hasOwnProperty(time)){
                text += ('\r\n' + time + " = " + measures[time]);
            }
        }
    }
}

$(document.getElementById('chart_div')).text(text);
```

And my `jsonData` looks like this:

```
    jsonData = '{"sensor1":
                  {"Date(2016,1,08,10,30,03)":19.187,
                   "Date(2016,1,08,10,00,02)":18.937[,...]},
                 "sensor2":
                  {"Date(2016,1,08,10,30,04)":18.687,
                   "Date(2016,1,08,10,00,03)":18.437[,...]}
                [,...]}'
```

My Problem is that i don't get the values "sensor1", "sensor2" and so on in the loop. `text += ('\r\n' + sensor);` only returns the `index` of the `sensor-object` in the `sensors-object`.

How can I get the sensor name instead of the index?

Comment: The string literal you are trying to assign to `jsonData` has a syntax error in it which will abort the script so none of your loops with every run.

Comment: @Quentin: I don't see the problem, i copy-pasted from running code. What do you mean? i only shorted it a bit for readability. So you could ignore [,...]

Comment: You can't have literal line breaks in a string literal in JS.

Comment: You should just use `var parsed = <?php echo $jsonTable ?>;`

Comment: Since JSON format is a subset of Javascript literal syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple workaround

Remove the `var sensors = [];`

Find `sensors` and replace with `parsed`.

**Code**:

```
for (var sensor in parsed){
if (parsed.hasOwnProperty(sensor)){
    var measures = parsed[sensor];
    text += ('\r\n' + sensor);
    console.log(parsed);
    for (var time in measures){
        if(measures.hasOwnProperty(time)){
            text += ('\r\n' + time + " = " + measures[time]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what solved the problem after @Quentin giving me his answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the sensor name instead of the index?

You need to do something with the property name in your **first loop**.

At present you are taking the property name (`sensor1`), using it to get the value (`{"Date...`) and then putting the value in an array while discarding the property name.

The simplest option would be to get rid of your first loop entirely and work with `parsed` instead of `sensors` in your second loop.

Comment: thats the hint i needed. i 'don't know why i tried to make an array from an object. I solved it by simply using the parsed object for my loops